# Keyword driven framework (Selenium) in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, reflection

I have created a Hybrid framework (Keyword driven + TestNG). It is in Java and to execute the methods, I use reflections in Java. The code is in such a way that I am executing all methods (Action Keywords) using a single line of code (method[i].invoke()) Reflections and hence all the methods have to take same number and the same type of inputs. Is there a way in java that we can implement keyword driven framework without reflections or a better approach to achieve keyword driven framework with reflections?

Comment: Add the relevant code...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. We can create keyword driven framework with keyword methods having the different number of parameters. Please check http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/keyword-driven-framework-example